# Modify coordinates with pixels in Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates

I´m using Google Maps and trying to move the `camera` to a certain position using Latitude and Longitude. I don´t want to use `scrollBy` method provided in `Camera` object because I want to get the new Latitude and Longitude after the modification.

```
val myLocation = LatLng(lat,lng)
val latitudeOffset = 100 // pixels 
val cameraCenter = getModifiedLocation(myLocation, latitudeOffset)
moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(cameraCenter, CAMERA_ZOOM))
```

I´ve tried using something like this

```
fun getModifiedLocation(location, latitudeOffset) {
 val offsetInCoordinates = latitudeOffset / 2.pow(CAMERA_ZOOM)
 return LatLng(location.latitude - offsetInCoordinates, location.longitude)
}
```

The thing is that `offsetInCoordinates` is moving the camera more pixels than the expected.

[image]

Comment: For anyone looking for this, you can add required padding to map view from bottom then center the map on the pin. then set the padding to zero. Hackish, but works.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the latitude and longitude of a xy position on the map you can use the `fromScreenLocation()` method.

Use something like:

```
LatLng latLng = map.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(new Point(x,y));
```

where x and y are the point on the map view "map".

You can also use the `toScreenLocation()` in order to get the xy-position of the given LatLng.

```
Point pt = map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(latLng);
```

Comment: Hi Barns, thank you for your answer. I prefer not to use any `map`method. I want to calculate the new coordinates avoiding to wait for the map to be loaded or the marker to be added.

Comment: @FranRios :: So you want to have the map centered on some arbitrary 100 pixels(!) latitude shift from the "myLocation"? Why pixels? That has nothing to do with distance.

Comment: The thing is that I want the map to be initialized with the camera at that position. If the position I pass to the camera is dependent on map methods to be computed, I won't get the proper camera input as any projection of the map is not pointing to where I want to get pointing to.

Comment: I uploaded a photo of what I want to render. As you can see I want the map to be full screen and render some cards in the top of it. I want the camera to be pointing immediately to the area the to the area so in order to do so I need coordinates of that area.

Comment: Wouldn't a physical distance of say 100 meters, for example be much better than 100 pixels?

Comment: I want to have the marker always at a fixed distance given in pixels from the top of the card

Comment: Because I want to have the marker always in the center of the top window. I know the position of the center but I cannot use any projection method because I want to calculate the coordinates if that point before the map is loaded in order to initialize the map with the camera pointing to that point.

Comment: I get it--You want some point 100 pixels relative to "myLocation"  (which I will assume is literally the actual location of the user) to be centered on the mapview. But, I just can't image any scenario where that could be useful to the user because pixels is not a physical distance--completely dependent on screen pixel density and zoom factor. This scenario makes no sense to me. However, calculating a known distance (eg. 100m) and placing that point at the center of the mapview where both points are visible on the map--zoomed to match that distance is do-able without first loading the map.

Comment: It is not that. I want 100 pixels relative to the top of the gray card. The zoom is constant to 16.0 and I know the location I want for the marker. I don't know the location I want the Camera to be centered at in order to render the marker in the center of the top view.

Answer (score 1):

I think this function should return `LatLng` that, if used to center the map upon should keep your pointer above your custom view, if you set appropriate dimen value for `map_center_pointer_vertical_offset` (for me `60dp` did the trick):

```
private fun calculateMapCenter(map: GoogleMap, markerPosition: LatLng): LatLng {
    val mapCenterPoint = map.projection.toScreenLocation(map.cameraPosition.target)
    val pointOffsetFromCenter = map.projection.fromScreenLocation(
        Point(
            mapCenterPoint.x,
            mapCenterPoint.y + resources.getDimension(R.dimen.map_center_pointer_vertical_offset).toInt()
        )
    )
    val latDelta = pointOffsetFromCenter.latitude - map.cameraPosition.target.latitude
    val lngDelta = pointOffsetFromCenter.longitude - map.cameraPosition.target.longitude
    return LatLng(markerPosition.latitude + latDelta, markerPosition.longitude + lngDelta)
}
```